# word meaning praising somebody or something that tends to be biased to others

Tags: single-word-requests

i was watching a collegiate volleyball game, and i noticed that one of the commentators was very partial to one team (the one from his alma mater), like he kept on saying all the great things (which are actually true) about that team, while virtually leaving the other team behind. what is the word for this ACTION, or PERSON?!

i need a word that denotes overpraising something because of a predilection, albeit everything about it is true.

Comment: *biased*, *chauvinistic*, *skewed*?

Answer (score 3):

An adjective that might serve your purposes is [***partisan***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan): ‘exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance’. As you say, such a person's commentary can actually be entirely accurate *as far as it goes*, but still fiercely biased.

The same word also works as a [noun](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/partisan): ‘a person who shows a biased, emotional allegiance’ (although as a noun it often indicates a combatant, not merely someone with a strong prejudice).

Answer (score 2):

I can't cite any dictionary authority for this, but a 'cheerleading' sportscaster is commonly referred to as a ***[homer](http://www.si.com/extra-mustard/2014/07/28/top-10-biggest-homer-announcers-sports)***. Google "sportscaster homer" for lots of examples.

Wikipedia does list this sense in [its glossary of baseball](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_baseball_(H)#homer), alongside the more familiar sense of "abbreviation for home run":

> ### homer
>
> A home run.
>
> **Also, a derisive term for a dedicated, almost delusional, fan.**
> **Especially used for a broadcaster, in any sport, whose team "can do no wrong".**
>
> Johnny Most of the Boston Celtics was a notorious "homer". In a somewhat more humorous example, Bert Wilson used to say, "*I don't care who wins, as long as it's the Cubs!*"
>
> A common "homer" saying is, "*My two favorite teams are* (my team) *and whoever's playing* (my team's rival)."

Presumably derived from the sense of "rooting for the *home* team" (the team based in and representing the homer's city or location), with the common *-er* suffix of agency, indicating "a person who does or subscribes to".

Comment: For the sake of a reference, I edited in a Wikipedia quote, along with some (admittedly unsubstantiated) etymological speculation. If it's a bridge too far, feel free to roll back or cut down the edit. It's your answer, not mine. You'll keep my +1 either way for teaching me a cool new word that I'd never encountered before.

Comment: @DanBron  No problem, your edits are welcome.